# Is there something similar to readyState from fetch() API?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I hope to write a front-end monitoring utility to record **server response time** and **content downloading time** for API calls.

Using XHR, `readyState` 3 (`LOADING`) indicating downloading begins.

How can I get similar information from `fetch()` API?

Comment: i don't think you can right now.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `PerformanceObserver()` [Count console.log objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167305/count-console-log-objects/41257158#41257158) and `Performance`. You can also utilize `EventSource` see [How to read and echo file size of uploaded file being written at server in real time without blocking at both server and client?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42475492/how-to-read-and-echo-file-size-of-uploaded-file-being-written-at-server-in-real)