# How to get current size of console log in Chrome DevTools

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a lot of console logging in one script.
How can I check size of current console log content?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41167305/count-console-log-objects ?

Comment: Will this help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627113/save-the-console-log-in-chrome-to-a-file

Comment: Yes this should be marked as duplicate. I did not know to ask smarter.
"Count console.log objects" is the key here. Thank you.